# Hide the contents of directories and disable directory browsing for all directories except specific ones

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I try hide the contents of directories and disable directory browsing for all directories except a few specific directories where it should be allowed.

I try to allow it on **www.mysite.de/new/audio** and **www.mysite.de/new/images**.

### .htaccess:

---

```
# Disable directory browsing (works)
Options -Indexes

# Hide the contents of directories (works)
IndexIgnore *

# Exceptions (not working -> 500 internal error)
<Directory "/new/audio">
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>

<Directory "/new/images">
    Options +Indexes
</Directory>
```

But then the whole site does not work anymore and fails with **Internal Server Error 500**.

Comment: What is your Apache version?

Comment: btw you're getting 500 because `Directory` isn't allowed in .htaccess